# Push Notifications remove subscriptions

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am building a push notifications system using nodejs as back-end where all my subscriptions are stored. The front-end client is vanilla js where I am creating a subscription per service worker, the subscription is then posted to the back-end server. What I want is to delete the subscription once that service worker's life's end due to any reason (manually uninstall, clear site data etc). How can this be achieved? Is there a pattern for this sort of problem?

As far as I know the subscription is useless once the service worker is uninstalled, so how can I perform this cleanup?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: My solution of this problem: remove registration of subscription on server side when an attempt to send notification returns `404` or `410`.

Comment: My advice is to use FireBase as a push message provider as they support Topic-based subscriptions so your code does not have to worry about maintaining a subscribers database. W3C deprecated this essential business requirement because message content could not be hidden from GCM/FCM.

Comment: BTW, if you're searching the web, another term for Topic-based messaging is Broadcast messaging. Why W3C insist on deliberately ham-stringing Web Apps escapes me :-(

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Thanks for the suggestion. That's what I'll do for now, seems quick and easy.

Comment: @McMurphy Won't I have to save the token on server?

Comment: IIUC you never know who's subscribed. You publish to "FootyScores" and whoever subscribes gets it.